# Using webview to load image from rest server in Android

Tags: android, rest, webview

I have a rest server hosted in Amazon written in Delphi with a method returning  a jpg Stream image.
I need download the image and show in webview.
The method Rest Server method is something as:

```
//delphi code
function TSrvServerMetodos.ImagePac(pront:integer): TStream;
var blob:TStream;
begin
    ...
    Result := CreateBlobStream(fieldbyname('PHOTO'),bmRead);
end;
```

where the Result is a jpeg Stream with a image.

To access the remote rest method I am trying to use the next:

```
String url = Common.getServerUrl() +"/"+ "\"ImagePac\"";
String URL=url+"/"+"23";
webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

But no Image is showing in webview.
My image is comming from a rest server and no a website. I have no way to call something  as webview.loadUrl("http://www.myserver.com/myimage.jpg");

Is possible load that image with webview?

Regards, Luiz

Comment: Is URL correct? Check in your web browser.

Comment: Yes, It is. To solve the problem I had to save the image to sdcard and create a html string to load the image with webview.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, It is. To solve the problem I had to save the image to sdcard and create a html string to load the image with webview.

For the new offspring with the same trouble. Just encode image in base64 and place it in src attribute of img tag